# Hide Column in Excel using C# and Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to hide column in Excel sheet using C# and Interop. I have used the below code. When I download my Excel sheet hidden columns are still there but my first column in Excel sheet starts from unhidden column. How can I completely get off the hidden columns.

Here is my sample code.

```
foreach (var item in hideColumnNames) 
{
   columnIndex = Array.IndexOf(dataColumn, item);
   excelWorkSheet.get_Range(excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, columnIndex], excelWorkSheet.Cells[excelWorkSheet.Rows.Count, columnIndex]).EntireColumn.Hidden = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Do you want to *completely get off the hidden columns*? Or, hide first column in your Excel?

Comment: I wanted to completely hide the list of columns. I figure out the solution. 
Actually I was calling the AutoFit() after hiding the columns. 
I solved the problem by calling AutoFit() method before calling the method which was hiding my columns.

Comment: excelWorkSheet = WorkSheetFunctions(excelWorkSheet, dataTable, dataColumn);
               excelWorkSheet = WorkSheetUI(excelWorkSheet, dataTable, dataColumn);
                excelWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                excelWorkSheet = HideWorkSheetColumns(excelWorkSheet, dataTable, dataColumn);